# edit display of php recordSet output

Tags: php, recordset

The following code produces each result as text.  I would like to add some html to each result, to change it from regular text to an href tag:

```
while (!$recordSet->EOF()) {
        if ($pclass_name_list == '') {
            $pclass_name_list .= $recordSet->fields['class_name'];
        } else {
            $pclass_name_list .= ',' . $recordSet->fields['class_name'];
        }
        $recordSet->MoveNext();
    }
```

The above produces Result 1, Result 2.  I'd like to change these to

```
<a href="">Result 1</a>
<a href="">Result 2</a>
```

etc..

Comment: html uses `<>` around tags not `[]`

Comment: Is your problem that you don't know html or you don't know how to mix html with php?

Comment: thx @JasonFuller - I didn't know how to mix php with html.  I had tried inserting the "echo" tag which threw an error.

Comment: @vascowhite - tried that initially but the <> tags were stripped so I had to use [] !

Comment: There you go, fixed it for ya :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing a simple addition of content into a string, you can either wrap the variable in curly braces and include it in a string that has double quotes (as below), or you can use the [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function to merge content into a template.

```
$pclass_name_list = array();
while (!$recordSet->EOF()) {
   $current_class_name = $recordSet->fields['class_name'];
   $pclass_name_list[] = "<a href=\"#\">{$current_class_name}</a>";
   $recordSet->MoveNext();
}
$pclass_name_list = implode(", ", $pclass_name_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
if ($pclass_name_list == '') {
        $pclass_name_list .= '<a href="">' . $recordSet->fields['class_name'] . '</a>';
} else {
        $pclass_name_list .= ', <a href="">' . $recordSet->fields['class_name'] . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: this too is a great answer that I can use if I need an if/else situation so thank you very much, much appreciated.